How to Validate rust FFI code against C Header file?
I am currently working on a project where I was given a C header (.h) file and need to implement it. My hope is that I can do so in Rust using FFI. Obviously there is no way to "import/implement" a header file directly in Rust so I would like to at least verify that given what I wrote it actually implements the header file at build time. That way if the headers change or the implementation does not match the headers, the build will fail.
Is there any way that I can verify that the rust code I wrote implements a specified header file?

Just use bindgen

bindgen?

cbindgen is probably more relevant here…

@Jmb that solves the opposite problem of generating a C header from Rust sources while OP wants to generate (or rather verify) Rust sources from a C header. I.e. that helps you generate a C header, but OP already "was given a C header".

@cafce25 OP wants to check that their manually written Rust code matches the API described in a given C header → one way to do that is to regenerate a C header from their Rust code and try to pass their C test suite with the generated C header instead of the given one.

@Jmb Generating a (possibly conflicting) duplicate C header seems like a very roundabout way to solve that problem. Just generate the external bindings from the C header and the compiler will tell you if you mess up, no need to run test cases, just compiling will ensure you've adhered to the header.

@cafce25 How can the compiler tell you if you mess up? Remember that the objective is not to call the API from Rust but instead to implement it in Rust.
